# Tabbed menu Bar Using Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to Javascript I want to create tabbed menu bar in that menu bar when user click on the tab it should change the back ground color of that tab and previous tab should come to Normal(Color less).And clicked color tab should in changed color.

Example:

**Home**  **Settings**  **Users**
Are the menu options when user click on settings it should highlight and remaining two are non-highlight how can I achive this using java script or CSS

I am using Table and sample code is 
                                
                                    
                                        ">**Home**
                                     

                                        ">**Users**

Comment: [Here is a tutorial on how to create a CSS drop down menu](https://www.servage.net/blog/2009/03/20/create-a-cool-css-based-drop-down-menu/). If you still have questions after following this tutorial then show where you are having problems in your code and we will do our best to help you.

Comment: @My Head Hurts — Tool cool for people who can't (or don't) use a mouse though. It fails to support non-pointer based navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a tutorial for setting up a simple tabbed menu with CSS and HTML](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-tabs-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo: are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/bUuwK/ ? (it uses jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

How about styling a `<input type="radio">`?

```
<form name="menubar" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="homeRadio" type="radio" name="menu" value="Home" />
    <label for="homeRadio">Home</label><br />
    <input id="settingsRadio" type="radio" name="menu" value="Settings" />
    <label for="settingsRadio">Settings</label><br />
    <input id="usersRadio" type="radio" name="menu" value="Users" />
    <label for="usersRadio">Users</input><br />
</form>
```

It would be easier to have the menu generated with server side scripting (like PHP), or JavaScript, but it could be built by hand if necessary.  The CSS to style the code would be something like the following.

```
form[name=menubar] input[type=radio][name=menu] {
    display: none;
}
form[name=menubar] input[type=radio][name=menu] + label {
    background-color: lightGrey;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}
form[name=menubar] input[type=radio][name=menu][checked=false] + label {
    font-weight:bold;
}
form[name=menubar] input[type=radio][name=menu][checked=true] + label {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

To access the onclick event, you could use some JavaScript code like:

```
<script>
    function menuItemClicked(name) {
        /* run some code here (the value of the element is passed as name) */
    }
    for(element in document.menubar.children) {
        document.menubar.children[element].onclick = function (element) {
            menuItemClicked(document.menubar.clildren[element].value);
        }
    }
</script>
```